# iOS - Using PubNub to send Apple Push Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pubnub

I am integrating PubNub (a service that allows devices to send messages to each other) into my iOS application.

I have followed the instructions on the page: http://www.pubnub.com/docs/ios-objective-c/mobile-gateway

I have registered for push notifications in my **AppDelegate.m**:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 8.0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge
                                                                                             |UIUserNotificationTypeSound
                                                                                             |UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    }

    return YES;
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
    NSLog(@"Application registered for push notifications");
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Device failed to register for push:");
}

-(void) application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    NSLog(@"Received push");
}
```

And I am sending the notification in my **ViewController**:

```
NSDictionary *push = @{@"pn_apns" :
                               @{@"aps" : @{
                                         @"alert" : @"notification"
                                         }
                                 }
                           };

[self.pubNub sendMessage:@"sample" applePushNotification:push toChannel:[PNChannel channelWithName:@"test channel"] compressed:NO withCompletionBlock:^(PNMessageState state, id data) {
        switch (state) {
            case PNMessageSending:
                NSLog(@"sending message");
                break;

            case PNMessageSendingError:
                NSLog(@"error sending message");
                break;

            case PNMessageSent:
                NSLog(@"message sent");
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
```

I get the message sent callback, but the push notification is not delivered onto the second device.

Comment: Hey! I don't see you associating the device UUIDs with the channel. That's mentioned in the tutorial. Try that, and if it doesn't work, feel free to contact us at support@pubnub.com

As well, feel free to check out our new 4.0 sdk that launched yesterday!

Comment: Send details about your issue to support@pubnub.com: PubNub SDK version, code, sub-key and we'll help you and post back here with public-safe answer. Reference this SO link in your email to us.